# Middleware for authenticating GitHub webhooks

Tags: php, authentication, stream, git

I'm currently working on a PSR-15 middleware for authenticating GitHub webhooks.

```php
<?php

class Auth implements MiddlewareInterface, LoggerAwareInterface
{
    const LOG_MSG_MISSING_HEADER = 'Authentication failed, X-Hub-Signature missing';
    const LOG_MSG_SIGNATURE_NOT_MATCHING = 'Authentication failed, signature did not match';
    const LOG_MSG_SUCCESS = 'Authentication successful';

    use LoggerAwareTrait;
    private const SIGNATURE_NAME = 'X-Hub-Signature';
    private $responseFactory;
    private $secret;
    public function __construct(string $secret, ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory)
    {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->logger = new NullLogger();
    }

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        if (!$request->hasHeader(self::SIGNATURE_NAME)) {
            $this->logger->warning(self::LOG_MSG_MISSING_HEADER);
            return $this->responseFactory->createResponse(400, 'Bad Request');
        }

        $signature = $this->getSignature($this->secret, $request->getBody());

        if (!hash_equals($request->getHeader(self::SIGNATURE_NAME)[0], $signature)) {
            $this->logger->warning(self::LOG_MSG_SIGNATURE_NOT_MATCHING);
            return $this->responseFactory->createResponse(401, 'Unauthorized');
        }

        $this->logger->info(self::LOG_MSG_SUCCESS);
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }

    private function getSignature(string $secret, string $body): string
    {
        return 'sha1=' . hash_hmac('sha1', $body, $secret);
    }
}
```

*I have removed comments and the use statements for the sake of brevity.
The complete code lives in this [repo](https://github.com/anfly0/PSR-15-github-auth/tree/d72653220b1e89e2b2b802de0dc2f3d28ea9d5e5).*

At the moment, I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the case if the stream representing the request body is not seekable.

The problem this introduces is that when the handler is called, it might not be possible to rewind the stream.
This will, of course, makes it impossible for any subsequent handlers/middlewares to access the body content.

As I see it, there are two options:

1. Check if the stream is seekable and throw an exception if it's not.

   *This solution is simple and would not introduce any real complexity.
   On the other hand, it shifts responsibility to the calling code, and that might not be the cleanest way of handling the issue.*
2. Change the constructor signature to require a PSR-17 StreamFactory and use that to create a new seekable stream and copy the content from the original non-seekable stream to the new one.

Any feedback on this or any other part of the code is most welcome!